# Question regarding rice theorem

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, rice-theorem, decidability

**this is a question I got from a test that we had before**

Let there be X, a subgroup of languages above $\Sigma $ such that X isn't empty nor all of the langauges in $\Sigma $ we need to say if the language L = {< M >| L(M) $\in$ X} is decidable.

In the answer they said that there is an X, which is X = $P(\Sigma^*)/L^c_{acc}$ we can see that X $\neq$ $\emptyset$ and that X isn't  $P(\Sigma^*)$ and then we get that

L = { < M >| L(M) $\in$ X} = { < M >| L(M) $\in$ X$\cap$RE} = { < M >| L(M) $\in$ RE} =
{ < M >| where < M > is a valid coding of a turing machine} $\in$ R

can someone clarify why this isn't right because of rice theorem and also why can we do the first move, where we did X intersection RE, why can we do it?